# how to remove blue background on text input css

Tags: css, input

i want to remove the blue color that appears on user input

```
<div class="textbox">
                <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                <input type="email"  placeholder="Email" name="email" class="inputs">  
            </div>
```

[illustration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ickDY.png)

This is the CSs for the inputs

```
.inputs:focus{
                outline: none;
                border-bottom-color:#75EFDA;
                transition:0.1s;
                transition-delay:0.2s;
                background: white;
              }
 .inputs{
            border:none;
            outline: none;
            color:black;
            font-size: 18px;
            width:80%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            animation: 1.5s grow;

             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because of auto-filling the input fields